# How to properly set url-routing for tx-news in TYPO3 9.5.5?

Tags: typo3, url-routing, tx-news, typo3-9.x

I use TYPO3 V9.5.5 with PHP V7.2.10. Also there is tx-news plugin installed. The site configuration is set and works. But if I add routeEnhancers for news detail it doesnt't show it in the url. It always looks like: http://p510984.mittwaldserver.info/aktuell/detail?tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=5&cHash=c68f25c1ef4b5bd7320220373cfed332

I searched for solutions in stackoverflow and google. Also I read the manual of the news extension https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/stable/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Routing/

Even TYPO3 and PHP cache flushing doesn't help.

At the moment I have following code:

```
routeEnhancers:
  NewsPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 17
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/{news_title}', _controller: 'News::detail', _arguments: {'news_title': 'news'} }
    defaultController: 'News::list'
    defaults:
      page: '0'
    aspects:
      news-title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
        routeFieldName: path_segment
```

Does it need "defaultController and defaults: page: 0"?

Comment: under aspects, it seems you misspelled "news-title". It should be "news_title" (same as in routes -> arguments).

Comment: @Nitori: Thank you for showing me the typo. But unfortunately that doesn't change anything.

Comment: I could resolve it! In my Sitepackage which I took from TYPO3 V8.7 I forgot that I had following code: `plugin.tx_news.seetings.link.skipControllerAndAction = 1`.
After I uncommented it, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Thats my config that works fine for me, maybe this helps...

```
News:
type: Extbase
extension: News
plugin: Pi1
routes:
  - routePath: '/'
    _controller: 'News::list'
  - routePath: '/page-{page}'
    _controller: 'News::list'
    _arguments:
      page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
  - routePath: '/{news-title}'
    _controller: 'News::detail'
    _arguments:
      news-title: news
  - routePath: '/{category-name}'
    _controller: 'News::list'
    _arguments:
      category-name: overwriteDemand/categories
  - routePath: '/{category-name}/page-{page}'
    _controller: 'News::list'
    _arguments:
      category-name: overwriteDemand/categories
      page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
defaultController: 'News::list'
defaults:
  page: '0'
aspects:
  news-title:
    type: PersistedAliasMapper
    tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
    routeFieldName: path_segment
  page:
    type: StaticRangeMapper
    start: '1'
    end: '100'
  category-name:
    type: PersistedAliasMapper
    tableName: sys_category
    routeFieldName: slug
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nitori already mentioned in the comment, you need to unify the spelling of `news_title` / `news-title`.

But this doesn't seem to be your only problem. Without the aspect, your URL should at least look like:

```
http://p510984.mittwaldserver.info/aktuell/detail/5&cHash=c68f25c1ef4b5bd7320220373cfed332
```

This means, the whole route is currently not applied to your detail page.

As you use `limitToPages`, please check if `17` is the UID of your detail page.

---

For the pagination widget, category plugins etc. you will need to add the related page UIDs to `limitToPages`, and of course extend your routes. [The news documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Routing/Index.html) shows examples for these use cases.

Comment: @sebkin: Thank you for your hint. Yes 17 is id of detail page. Even without the aspect part it shows url like this: http://p510984.mittwaldserver.info/aktuell/detail?tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=5&cHash=c68f25c1ef4b5bd7320220373cfed332
That behaviour is very odd?!
So I wonder does it work with TYPO3 V9.5.5?

Comment: Does it help if you remove `limitToPages` from your configuration (and clear all caches afterwards)? I copied your configuration to my local environment. It works as expected after I applied the described changes.

Comment: @sebkin: I removed ```limitToPages``` and it doesen't change anything. Did you test it with TYPO3 V9.5.5?

Comment: Yes, it is TYPO3 9.5.5. As indentation is important for YAML configuration, it's better to update the config in your question.

Comment: How are the links generated? Using the n:link viewhelper? Or something custom (f:link.acton or similar)? If latter, I noticed that leaving out the `controller` and `action` from the url parameters might cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

For me this one worked well:

```
routeEnhancers:
  # news rewrites
  News:
    type: Extbase
    #limitToPages:
    #  - 67
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/{news-title}', _controller: 'News::detail', _arguments: { news-title: news } }
      #- { routePath: '/cat/{news-cat}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: { news-cat: overwriteDemand/categories } }
    defaultController: 'News::list'
    defaults:
      page: '0'
    aspects:
      news-title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
        routeFieldName: path_segment
      news-cat:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: sys_category
        routeFieldName: slug
```